# Netlogo: How to create a reporter that reports the furthest point away from starting point

Tags: netlogo

I have made a model on large predators. The model works fine but I would like to track how far the animal (turtle) moves away from its den (patch 50,50) each month (denoted by 30 x 86400 ticks)

Is it possible to report the furthest xcor ycor that the turtle moves to ?
I can code this to report monthly if you provide the code for the reporter.

kind regards

Kilian

Comment: Once approach: add a `maxdist` attribute to predators and each tick update it with `distance patch 50 50` whenever this is larger than the current `maxdist`.  At the beginning of each month, you can reset `maxdist`to `0`.

Comment: Thank you, i did something very similar!